# Quick Question - Complex Roots of Polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm asked to solve for Z where

$$\frac{z+i}{2z-i}  = \frac{-1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

As a result i got

$$2z = \sqrt{3}zi + \frac{i}{2} - i^2\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - i$$

The answer is supposed to be

$$z = 3\frac{\sqrt 3}{14} + \frac{i}{14}$$

I think i'm doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $z$ to get a quadratic in $z$ that you can then solve the usual way.

Comment: Since you are (relatively) new here, I wanted to let you know a few things: This site uses MatJaX to format Maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a quick tutorial. Also, I can see that you have not accepted any answers to your questions. If a question gets answers, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. For more information you can [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I should also mention that your titles are very uninformative. Please read: [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/145141)

Comment: This question is not perfect, sure, but guys, come on. It doesn't deserve the downvotes!

Comment: @5xum I can't speak for others, but my downvote will be removed when I see that the OP made an effort to use MathJaX, to (upvote and) accept answers to their question, ask a good question (with informative titles). Here I used my downvote to discourage "bad behaviour". This is also why I won't upvote (I didn't say downvote) the answer given to this question, because it would encourage encouraging people to ask bad questions. This is my humble opinion.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I would not do this to an entirely new user,  but the OP has ben a member for over a year and has asked 10 questions. I am seeing a bad habit developping here and am trying to stop it.

Comment: @gebruiker Maybe you can give him a chance to respond to your constructive criticism before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't cross multiply the $z$ correctly. Here is the right steps involved:

$$
2z + 2i = (-2z + i) + z * 2i\sqrt 3 + 1\sqrt 3 \\
2z + 2z - z * 2i\sqrt 3 = i + \sqrt 3 - 2i \\
4z - z * 2i\sqrt 3 = \sqrt 3 - i \\
z(4 - 2i\sqrt 3) = \sqrt 3 - i \\
z = \frac{\sqrt 3 - i}{4 - 2i\sqrt 3} \\
$$
Now, to rationalize the denominator, we multiply and divide by the conjugate of the denominator - $\overline{4 - 2i\sqrt3} = 4 + 2i \sqrt 3$
$$
z = \frac{(\sqrt 3 - i) * (4 + 2i\sqrt 3)}{(4 - 2i\sqrt 3) * (4 + 2i\sqrt 3)} \\
z = \frac{4 \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 3 . 2i \sqrt 3 - 4i - 2 i^2 \sqrt 3}{4^2 - (2 i \sqrt 3)^2} \\
z = \frac{4 \sqrt 3 + 6i - 4i + 2 \sqrt 3}{16 - (- 4 . 3)} \\
z = \frac{6 \sqrt 3 + 2i}{28} \\
z = \frac{3 \sqrt 3 + i}{14} \\
$$

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is to keep the computations at a minimum, in order to not get lost. So I suggest giving a symbolic name to the right-hand side:
$$
w=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
So the equation becomes
$$
\frac{z+i}{2z-i}=w
$$
Cross multiply and move terms around in the usual way
$$
z-2wz=-wi-i
$$
that becomes
$$
z=\frac{i(w+1)}{2w-1}
$$
Now let's compute $2w-1$:
$$
2w-1=-1+i\sqrt{3}-1=-2+i\sqrt{3}
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{2w-1}=\frac{1}{-2+i\sqrt{3}}=\frac{-2-i\sqrt{3}}{7}
$$
We also have
$$
i(w+1)=\frac{i}{2}(1+i\sqrt{3})=\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{3}+i)
$$
and, finally,
$$
z=\frac{(-\sqrt{3}+i)(-2-i\sqrt{3})}{14}
$$
that you should be able to bring to normal form.